# Second to last record SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

New to SQL and trying to find the second too last priority level (an integer). SQL below keeps returning the latest priority level

```sql
select priority_level
from wers_assessment a
where
  a.client_id=rc.client_id and
  assessment_id = (
    select max(assessment_id)
    from wers_assessment aa
    where aa.client_id = a.client_id and priority_level < (
      select max(assessment_id)
      from wers_assessment aa
      where aa.client_id = a.client_id
    )
  )
```

Comment: `priority_level < (
      select max(assessment_id)` What's `priority_level`'s relationship to `assessment_id`?

Comment: Query in a query in a query. Hmm.

Comment: I don't see any definition of "rc." should that be that "aa."?

Comment: Are you trying to find second to last priority_level or assessment_id?

Answer (score 0):

Please post some data!! cant help much with what you have provided.. but that aside the gist of what you want to do is this

```
(SELECT priority_level 
 FROM wers_assessment a
 WHERE a.client_id=rc.client_id 
   AND assessment_id = 
   (   SELECT MAX(assessment_id)
       FROM wers_assessment aa
       WHERE aa.client_id = a.client_id
   )
 ORDER BY priority_level DESC 
 LIMIT 2
) 
ORDER BY priority_level ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

NOTE this is using the UNION syntax to do a double order by on the single select